# What is the height distribution of elfs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size

This question may sound weird, but I could not find a good answer so far. All the sources cite that elfs are "*taller than humans*", but not how much taller or how much their height varies.

Given that most women are between 150 - 170 cm and most men between 165 - 185 cm ([according to a quick google search](https://www.google.at/search?q=human%20height%20distribution)), I wonder how the same height distribution looks like for elfs. Are female elfs generally smaller than male elfs? And by how much are elfs in general taller than humans? Is an 190cm female elf average, or especially short/tall?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Many races have tables for determining heights and weights

*Pathfinder* elves' heights and weights can be determined officially using this [table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf#TOC-Random-Height-and-Weight). Humans' heights and weights can be determined officially using this [table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human#TOC-Random-Height-and-Weight). Many official races also have similar tables.

Average male elves are 6' 1" (185 cm) and 137 lbs. (62 kg), and average female elves are 5' 11" (180 cm) and 111 lbs. (50 kg). Average male humans are 5' 9" (175 cm) and 175 lbs. (80 kg), and average human females are 5' 4" (162 cm) and 140 lbs. (63 kg)

Comment: Oh, seems as if I just overlooked this table. This is a little embarassing.

Comment: Incidentally, it might be worth noting that the table doesn't give a totally accurate representation of human height/weight ranges. It is, of course, up to each group to decide what this means for their campaign, but one common interpretation is that the table represents a 'good enough' approximation of the common ranges that most individuals fall into, and that exceptions can and do exist in the wider population - and that the tables for non-human races have a similar degree of inaccuracy.